# Calling a method from functions.php on a click of a button

Tags: php, functions, javascript, html, user-meta

I have been working on a project where I will have to call a method(that accepts user id as an input) from a click of a submit button(Accept button).

I have been trying all the ways but the real challenge I am facing is how to get the user id in the front end and pass it to the method.

My method updates the user meta of that particular user.

**Html code:**

```
<div id="modal">
    <div class="modalconent">
         <h3 align=center>GDPR</h3>

        <p>This is a GDPR Pop Up</p><br><br><br>
        <form>
            <input name="accept" type="checkbox" value="Gdpr" required/>I accept the GDPR
            <input type="submit" id="accept-button" value="Accept">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('accept-button').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('modal').style.display = "none"
    };
};
</script>
```

At present, my Accept button when clicked is only displaying none. I want to call the method along with display:none;

**My PHP code:**

```
function updateHasReadFlag($user) {
  // I added support for using this function either with user ID or user object
  if ( $user && is_int( $user ) ) {
    $user_id = $user;
  } else if ( ! empty( $user->ID ) ) {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
  } else {
    return;
  }
  return update_user_meta( $user_id, 'META_KEY', true );
}
```

**The form code generated :**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
             <input name="accept" type="checkbox" value="Gdpr" required=""> I accept the GDPR
             <input type="submit" id="accept-button" value="Accept">
             <!--?php wp_nonce_field( 'accept-gdpr', 'accept_gdpr_nonce' ); ?-->
        </form>
```

I do not understand why nonce field is commented. This is exactly what the code got generated, I have not edited anything in the code.

Comment: Are you trying to update the metadata without reloading the current page? How about simply submitting the form to the same page and update the metadata on page load?

Comment: Yes I am trying to update metadata. Can you provide me some solution of what you are talking about. It would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AJAX if you don't want to reload the current page — i.e. upon clicking the "Accept" button, make an AJAX request to update the user metadata, all without leaving the current page.

However, the solution I'm proposing is *not* using AJAX; instead, we simply submit the form (set its `action` attribute value) to the homepage and then we use the `template_redirect` hook to update the metadata (and redirect back to the previous or referring page).

### The Steps

1. Change the `form` tag to:

   ```
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
   ```

   and add this [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) field:

   ```
   <?php wp_nonce_field( 'accept-gdpr', 'accept_gdpr_nonce' ); ?>
   ```

   so your `form` now looks like:

   ```
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
       <input name="accept" type="checkbox" value="Gdpr" required /> I accept the GDPR
       <input type="submit" id="accept-button" value="Accept" />
       <?php wp_nonce_field( 'accept-gdpr', 'accept_gdpr_nonce' ); ?>
   </form>
   ```
2. Add this to the theme `functions.php` file:

   ```
   function accept_gdpr() {
       // Check if the user is authenticated.
       if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
           return;
       }

       // Check if we have all necessary data.
       if ( empty( $_POST['accept_gdpr_nonce'] ) || empty( $_POST['accept'] ) ||
           'Gdpr' !== $_POST['accept'] ) {
           return;
       }

       // Verify the nonce.
       if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['accept_gdpr_nonce'], 'accept-gdpr' ) ) {
           return;
       }

       // Update the meta.
       update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'META_KEY', '1' );

       // Redirect back to the previous page.
       wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
       exit;
   }
   add_action( 'template_redirect', 'accept_gdpr' );
   ```

   **Notes:**

   1. The `Gdpr` as in `'Gdpr' !== $_POST['accept']` is the same as in the `<input name="accept" type="checkbox" value="Gdpr" required />` above.
   2. *Be sure to replace the `META_KEY` with the actual meta key.*
   3. I believe that the GDPR acceptance is aimed at logged-in users only, so that's why I used `is_user_logged_in()` and `get_current_user_id()` in the above code/function.

### UPDATE

`wp_safe_redirect()` didn't work for the OP, so he used `wp_redirect()`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) also available [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).
Short story : it's the WordPress way to call `PHP` in `JS`
So you could do something like the following.
**FIRST** create a `js` folder at the root of your theme, same level as style.css, if you do not have one yet, then in this `js` folder create a file `call-php.js`. You can name it what ever you want, the important thing is that it has to be a `.js` file
In your **functions.php** **after** your `function updateHasReadFlag($user)` add :

```
/**
 * Hooking in JS code.
 */
function call_php_in_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'call-php-in-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/call-php.js', array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/call-php.js' ) ), true );
    $php_to_js = array(
        'my_php_function' => updateHasReadFlag( $user ),
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'call-php-in-js', 'object_name', $php_to_js );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'call_php_in_js' );
```

**SECOND**, in the `call-php.js` file add :

```
( function( $ ) {
    $( "#accept-button" ).click( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $( "#modal" ).hide();
        object_name.my_php_function;
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

Hope this will solve your issue.
I didn't test it but it should work.
Let me know after testing it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I appreciate it. But somehow this is not working. My `function updateHasReadFlag($user)` is not getting called. Or may be it is getting called but the `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'META_KEY', true );` is somehow not working. Can you look into it. I have also removed `<script>` `</script>` from my html code.

Comment: Asking you just to confirm, My `function updateHasReadFlag($user)` accepts userID or user Object as a parameter, so it can update that particular user meta data. Are we sending this as a parameter when calling the `function updateHasReadFlag($user)`

Comment: could you please replace `object_name.my_php_function;` by `console.log(object_name.my_php_function);` and tell me what you see in the console. Just to know, is the `#modal` getting hide when you click on `#accept-button` using my answer ?

Comment: It is logged as "null" in the console for call-php.js

Comment: is the `#modal` getting hide when you click on `#accept-button` using my answer ?

Comment: yes @LebCit. It is getting hidden.

Comment: could you please use [BugFu Console Debugger](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bugfu-console-debugger/) on your `function updateHasReadFlag($user)` to see the exact output, if it's working... Tell me when you do it, I think that you'll catch whats the problem.

Comment: I have used BugFu debugger. `my_php_function` is null. That's what I found.

Comment: I think I have the found an issue. My php code `updateHasReadFlag($user)`  is in my child theme, where as `call-php.js` is in my parent theme. `get_template_directory_uri()` is directing to the parent theme. So I thought that's why may be the `my_php_function` is null. But now I am directing everything to the child theme and `my_php_function` is still null.

Comment: You should do everything mentioned above ONLY in your child theme !!! So your function should go in functions.php of your child theme and all the steps in my answer should be applied in the child theme.

Comment: Yes I did that. I have replaced `get_template_directory_uri()` with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` . and `filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/call-php.js' )` with `filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory( '/js/call-php.js' )` . but still the log is null.

Comment: Use the code as given ! `filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory( '/js/call-php.js' )` is wrong ! If you want to change this it should be `filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory()  . '/js/call-php.js' )`. ! Check the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) before making changes. I think that you are making a wrong call of action on your php function.

Comment: What did you mean by "making a wrong call of action on your php function". My function in functions.php is just as same as in my question.