# Submitting form via admin-post.php and handling errors

Tags: php, forms

I have a custom form I'm adding to a page by using a page template (I don't want to use a plugin for specific reasons).  I'm submitting this form using `admin-post.php`.  Inside `functions.php` I have my function to process the form, which is working.  I can display the validation errors on the blank `admin-post.php` but obviously that isn't want I want.

**So here are my questions.**

- Am I supposed to just do normal redirects back to my form page? 
  Something like `wp_redirect( '/my-page/',302);`?
- How do I display my errors on the page that has the form?
- On success, how do I replace the form with a success message?

I feel like I'm missing a crucial piece of the puzzle...

**Here is a stripped down version of the form.**

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" method="post">
    <label for="tos_agree">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tos_agree" id="tos_agree" <?php if ($_POST['tos_agree']){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
        Some text for the checkbox
    </label>

    <button type="submit" name="agree" value="I Agree">I Agree</button>

    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="updated_tos_agree" />
</form>
```

**And My Function**

```
function updated_tos_agree_submit() {

    function form_submit() {
        $error = new WP_Error();

        if (!$_POST['tos_agree']){
            $error->add('notchecked','You must agree to the Terms.');
        }

        return $error;
    }

    $result = form_submit();

    if (is_wp_error($result)) {
        echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $result->get_error_messages() ) . '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }else{
        // Update User Meta
    }

    die();
}

add_action('admin_post_nopriv_updated_tos_agree', 'updated_tos_agree_submit');
add_action('admin_post_updated_tos_agree', 'updated_tos_agree_submit');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I supposed to just do normal redirects back to my form page?
>   Something like `wp_redirect( '/my-page/', 302 );`?

Yes.

> How do I display my errors on the page that has the form?

Well, there are various ways, including:

1. Passing an error code as a query string in the *redirect URL*: `example.com/my-page/?my_form_error=tos_agree_empty`. Then in your form/template, you could do something like `echo $messages[ $_GET['my_form_error'] ];` where `$messages` is an array of error messages. (Note: In actual implementation, you should *sanitize* the query value.)
2. Saving the error in a [transient](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/) — a temporary database option.

> On success, how do I replace the form with a success message?

Pretty much the same as with the above question. So you can:

1. Include a "success" status in the *redirect URL*: `example.com/my-page/?my_form_success=1`. Then in your form/template, you can do something like `if ( ! empty( $_GET['my_form_success'] ) ) { echo 'Success.'; } else { /* Display the form. */ }`.
2. Or once again, use the transient API to save (and also retrieve) the "success" status.

And you might find it useful by reading the article [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/) which explains in-depth about handling form submissions using the `admin-post.php`, plus it also talks about AJAX (`admin-ajax.php`) which is really good in that no page reloads would be necessary in submitting the form. However, you should instead use the REST API to create a [custom endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) for your form submissions. :)

So I hope this (new) answer helps you and you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/74c142e0ce0d0bafa643b6cf7c933acb) an example of using the transient API for persisting the form validation errors and submitted data to be used after being redirected from `admin-post.php`. I also hope the [linked answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/342453) helps, which gives an example of handling the form submission using [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) which is fired on the *same page* — the `admin_post_` hooks are fired on a different page in the admin (`wp-admin`) side of the site.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!